# WP7 Schedule to send sms at specific time?

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7.1

I have read on methods to set alarm and reminder. Any suggestion how to set a reminder to send an sms automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to send an sms automatically with windows phone, you always need user confirmation. You can set a reminder so that the user can send the sms manually.